# Converting SSIS packages into Cloud Azure

Tags: ssis, azure, cloud

how to convert SSIS packages into Cloud azure.

Also please can you tell me something about SSIS packages and what is not supported in CLoud.

Comment: what do you mean?  Are you trying to move data to the cloud or do you want to run the packages in the cloud?

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is not supported in SQL Azure at all for now.

If you have to run it, you have 3 options that I can see:

1. Install SQL Server standard on a VM role in the cloud and run it on that.
2. Put your database in the cloud, but run the package on a local machine and just connect to the remote database.
3. Rewrite your SSIS logic as an Azure worker role

Comment: Is it possible to run SSIS in a web role? I have no prior experience with SSIS. Can it be included in a web application as an assembly reference and executed somehow?

Comment: It's a windows service that has to be installed, so while it may be possible, it'll be really hard to setup and may not work due to permissions too. If you need it, best bet will be the new Azure VM roles they're 100x better than when I initially wrote this.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. I was just investigating it for now, to do fuzzy lookups, but am going on an alternative solution using stored procs for now (and since I'm hosting in a Web Role for now). Will keep that in mind for future.

Comment: @Doobi in your comment (two above mine) you mention the new Azure VM roles - well the "old" Azure VM roles feature is still there and uses this name, so to be clear (and I know you know this), the new feature of interest here is Windows Azure Virtual Machines (not a "role") which have persistent data storage (backed by Blob Storage) - learn more here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/

Answer (score 0):

eSSIS : https://www.dualcorp.fr/Product.aspx?id=jKIoPSeLL9plO8H1ZBAePg==
I install the dll on my sqlAzure server and I use it and I can manage my packages online.